# "Split" a image into packages of bytes

Tags: python, arduino

I am trying to do a project for college which consists of sending images using two Arduino Due boards and Python. I have two codes: one for the client (the one who sends the image) and one for the server (the one who receives the image). I know how to send the bytes and check if they are correct, however, I'm required to "split" the image into packages that have:

- a header that has a size of 8 bytes and must be in this order:

  1. the first byte must say the payload size;
  2. the next three bytes must say how many packages will be sent in total;
  3. the next three bytes must say which package I'm currently at;
  4. the last byte must contain a code to an error message;
- a payload containing data with a maximum size of 128 bytes;
- an end of package (EOP) sequence (in this case, 3 bytes).

I managed to create the end of package sequence and append it correctly to a payload in order to send, however I'm facing issues on creating the header.

I'm currently trying to make the following loop:

```
with open(root.filename, 'rb') as f:
    picture = f.read()

picture_size = len(picture)

packages = ceil(picture_size/128)
last_pack_size = (picture_size)

EOPs = 0
EOP_bytes = [b'\x15', b'\xff', b'\xd9']

for p in range(1,packages):
    read_bytes = [None, int.to_bytes(picture[(p-1)*128], 1, 'big'), 
        int.to_bytes(picture[(p-1)*128 + 1], 1, 'big')]
    if p != packages:
        endrange = p*128+1
    else:
        endrange = picture_size
    for i in range((p-1)*128 + 2, endrange):
        read_bytes.append(int.to_bytes(picture[i], 1, 'big'))
        read_bytes.pop(0)
        if read_bytes == EOP_bytes:
            EOPs += 1
    print("read_bytes:", read_bytes)
    print("EOP_bytes:", EOP_bytes)
    print("EOPs", EOPs)
```

I expect at the end that the server receives the same amount of packages that the client has sent, and in the end I need to join the packages to recreate the image. I can manage to do that, I just need some help with creating the header.

Comment: Just as a side note, I think you have client and server confused.

Comment: The client and server were predefined by my teacher

Comment: Then your teacher is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a a demo of how to construct your header, it's not a complete soultion but given you only asked for help constructing the header it may be what you are looking for.

```
headerArray = bytearray()

def Main():
    global headerArray

    # Sample Data
    payloadSize = 254 # 0 - 254
    totalPackages = 1
    currentPackage = 1
    errorCode = 101   # 0 - 254

    AddToByteArray(payloadSize,1)    # the first byte must say the payload size;
    AddToByteArray(totalPackages,3)  # the next three bytes must say how many packages will be sent in total;
    AddToByteArray(currentPackage,3) # the next three bytes must say which package I'm currently at;
    AddToByteArray(errorCode,1)      # the last byte must contain a code to an error message;

def AddToByteArray(value,numberOfBytes):
    global headerArray

    allocate = value.to_bytes(numberOfBytes, 'little')
    headerArray += allocate

Main()

# Output

print(f"Byte Array: {headerArray}")

for i in range(0,len(headerArray)):
    print(f"Byte Position: {i} Value:{headerArray[i]}")
```

Obviously I have not included the logic to obtain the current package or total packages.